# Unable to run Jmeter perfomance-toolkit for magento 2

Tags: magento2, testing

I am trying to run the jmeter benchmark.jmx in `setup/performace-toolkit` of Magento 2.

The tests are failing trying to log into the admin. The login form is posted to `${base_path}${admin_path}/admin/dashboard/` but this results in a `302` If I change the path to: `/index.php/admin/admin/index/index/key/29beedceb1eb856caffd426b4099ebb8a466a8d318536808181062ab066f79c4/`
the login is successful.

The problem appears to be that the JMeter tests are not using the `key` parameter.

Is this a problem with the JMeter tests or am I missing a configuration option within magento which removes then need for a key.

Answer (score 2):

you can skip security key check by configuration change.  also you can change rewrite mode instead of test fixing.
`php -f bin/magento setup:store-config:set --admin-use-security-key=0 --use-rewrites=1`

Answer (score 1):

The key parameter is a dynamic string, you can simply skip it to run your performance toolkit.
Go to Stores >> Configuration >> Admin >> Security >> Add Secret Key to URLs >> set as "No"
http://prntscr.com/msxya1